# Method for MenubarItem not functional when I put them in a Class, and instantiate this class In AppDelegate.swift, but they didn't work

Tags: swift, macos

I am learning to create a macos menubar extras app.
I write my menu in a standalone swift file `MenuController.swift`

```swift
import Cocoa

class MenuController: NSObject {
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem
    
    init(statusItem: NSStatusItem) {
        self.statusItem = statusItem
    }
    
        func setupMenus() {
            let menu = NSMenu()
    
            let settings = NSMenuItem(title: "Settings", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
            menu.addItem(settings)
            let settingsMenu = NSMenu()
            let openGoogle = NSMenuItem(title: "Open Google", action: #selector(openGoogle), keyEquivalent: "")
            settingsMenu.addItem(openGoogle)
            settings.submenu = settingsMenu
            menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
            menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))
            statusItem.menu = menu
        }
        
        
        @objc func openGoogle() {
            NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
        }

        func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
            // Insert code here to tear down your application
        }

        func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

}
```

I create two menubar item, one is `quit`  and another is `setting`, in `setting` I create `open google`.

I put each menubar item's corresponding method in the same class. Then I instantiate the class in `AppDelegated.swift`

```swift
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var menuController: MenuController?
    
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "1.circle", accessibilityDescription: "1")
        }
        
        let menuController = MenuController(statusItem: statusItem)
        menuController.setupMenus()
        
    }
}
```

Then I build and run my app and it turned out only the `quit` option is functional and the `Open Google` option is not work (it's gray)

**So I put copy all these functions (like `@objc func openGoogle`) to `AppDelegate.swift` and it works!**

Why?

Someone told me that if you create a MenuBarItem instance in another Class and specify the function of this instance as the target of the response event, the target may not be correctly registered with the NSApplication instance initialized by AppDelegate at startup.

I am really a newbie to macdev, and lacks of coding experience. Can you tell me the reasoning behind these phenomena?

Comment: I use Storyboard other than SwiftUI, because I found SwiftUI can not create multilevel menus using its original APIs.

Comment: FYI, I'm using XCode14, and macOS13 on a M1 MacMini,

Comment: See [Enabling Menu Items](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu item is grayed out because there is nothing in the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2) that responds to the `openGoogle` selector.

`AppDelegate` is part of the responder chain, and so is `NSApplication`. This explains why moving the method to `AppDelegate` works, and why the "Quit" menu item works.

You can set a `target` for the menu item, so that it sends the action message to the `target`, and not the responder chain.

```
openGoogle.target = self
```

Alternatively, make `MenuController` inherit from `NSResponder`, and set that as the `nextResponder` of `NSApplication.shared`, effectively adding it to the responder chain:

```
class MenuController: NSResponder {
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem
    
    init(statusItem: NSStatusItem) {
        self.statusItem = statusItem
        super.init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // ...
}

// in AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching
NSApplication.shared.nextResponder = menuController
```

Also, you should keep a reference of the `MenuController` somewhere, e.g. in the `AppDelegate`. Otherwise it will be deallocated, because `target` is a weak reference. There are no strong references to it after `applicationDidFinishLaunching` returns.

You can do this just by assigning the local `menuController` to the `menuController` property you declared in `AppDelegate`:

```
let menuController = MenuController(statusItem: statusItem)
menuController!.setupMenus()
self.menuController = menuController
```